# Can't get equal height columns and visible gutters

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a grid with equal height columns and visible gutters. I have equal height columns but I can't make visible gutters in the same background-color as the body-element (beige). I'm starting to think what I want to do is impossible with padding as gutters...

I'm thankful for all help I can get. [My code](https://jsfiddle.net/4asn13jc/4/)

**EDIT** I weren't clear enough with what I want. I want to be able to change the background-color on the body-element so it effects the gutter.Like you can with Bootstrap (which I've heard has it's gutter set in padding) [Bootstrap example](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ku12sd/)

Note that my own example only have one column size (.col-6) but I need to be able to use more columns of different sizes, that's the reason I haven't used margins instead, since it would be hard to calculate the size of them so all column-sizes + margins equals 100% width.

```css
body {
  background-color: beige;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-6 { 
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  padding-right: 1.4em;
  width: 50%;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.information {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/08/05/16/ancient-1807518_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="information">
      <p>Aenean tincidunt ornare lacinia. Suspendisse lacinia bibendum ex, vehicula faucibus mauris ornare at. Fusce nec magna tincidunt urna molestie fringilla.</p>
      <p>Nam fermentum, mauris eget elementum sodales, libero mauris egestas urna, vitae tempor felis felis eget augue.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it what you want?: https://jsfiddle.net/7z6hfoL6/

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: beige;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-6 { 
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  padding-right: 1.4em;
  width: 49%;
  margin-right:2%;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0px;
  float:right;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.information {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/08/05/16/ancient-1807518_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 float-right">
    <div class="information">
      <p>Aenean tincidunt ornare lacinia. Suspendisse lacinia bibendum ex, vehicula faucibus mauris ornare at. Fusce nec magna tincidunt urna molestie fringilla.</p>
      <p>Nam fermentum, mauris eget elementum sodales, libero mauris egestas urna, vitae tempor felis felis eget augue.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```